# Python Modulo Operator without An Equal Sign and A Not-Equal Sign

Tags: python, modulo

```py
def even_or_odd(number):
    return 'Odd' if number % 2 else 'Even'

print(even_or_odd(2))
```

Why does this Python code print Even instead of Odd?

Comment: Am I missing something here? It prints "Even", because the number 2 is even. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `number % 2`, where `number` is even, will give you zero. That's a falsey value in Python, hence the `if` will fail and it will output `Even`. It's no different to:

```py
>>> if 0:
...     print('zero')
... else:
...     print('nonzero')
...
nonzero
```

If you wanted the `if` statement to *succeed* for an even number, you would be better off using `number % 2 == 0`, which will give you `True` for even numbers. That equivalent statement would be written as:

```py
return 'Even' if number % 2 == 0 else 'Odd'
```

However, given your constraints in the title (no `==` or `!=`), that's not allowed<sup>(a)</sup>. The use of "reversed" logic gets around this problem.

---

By the way, other methods to do this could include (amongst probably a great many more):

```py
return 'Even' if not number % 2 else 'Odd'
return ['Even', 'Odd'][number % 2]
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Though I rather dislike artificial limitations of this type educators often slip into assignments. After all, when will a developer really be called upon to implement something without the `=` key? Maybe if their keyboard is broken? But then, your bigger issue is surely working for a company that won't shell out $5 for a new keyboard :-)

Comment: The reason I wrote that is to help those who have the same problem find this article easily. It is not a restriction, just wanted to clarify what was being asked here.